# Is there a more efficient way of reading BLOBs without writing them locally first?

Tags: java, database, oracle, blob

I want to be able to read a document from database and extract some data out of it. I am able to do the second part but I'm having issue with doing it efficiently. Is there a more efficient way of reading BLOBs without writing them locally first? As you can see I save the data into a document on my hard drive which is terribly slow.

```
final String url = "connectioninfo";
final String username = "user";
final String password = "password";

try {
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);

     String sql = "SELECT document_id, file_name, data FROM documents WHERE file_name like '%.doc'";
     PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
     ResultSet resultSet = stmt.executeQuery();

     while (resultSet.next()) {
          String da_document_id = resultSet.getString(1);
          String file_name = resultSet.getString(2);

          File data = new File("c:\\databaseDoc.doc");
          FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(data);

          byte[] buffer = new byte[1];
          InputStream is = resultSet.getBinaryStream(3);
          try {
            while (is.read(buffer) > 0) {
                fos.write(buffer);
            }
            fos.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        }


        System.out.println("da_document_id= " + da_document_id);
        System.out.println("file_name= " + file_name);
    }
    conn.close();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Well it's certainly going to be slow with a 1-byte sized buffer and using unbuffered streams.

Comment: What would be an appropriate size for the buffer?

Comment: You might want to tell us what you trying to do with the MS Word document. What do you mean by read the document? Do you want to extract specific data?

Comment: I want to 'scan' through the document and recognise certain keywords. Say the document contains 'Hello world'. I want to be able to see that this document has that string in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Apache POI to read the BLOBs inputstream directly without first writing the MS Word document to your filesystem.

```
XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(resultSet.getBinaryStream(3));
```

Comment: I am using Apache POI. This is the part I'm stuck on so you've basically went ahead and kind of suggested what to do next :) Cheers

Answer (score 4):

Part of the reason that it's slow is that you're reading *one byte* at a time. That's never a good idea. If you're using Java 9, I'd also suggest using `InputStream.transferTo(OutputStream)` to make things rather simpler:

But no, you don't need to write to a `FileOutputStream` - you could copy the data into a `ByteArrayOutputStream` instead, at which point you can easily create a `byte[]`:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
try (InputStream input = resultSet.getBinaryStream(3)) {
    input.transferTo(output);
}
byte[] data = output.toByteArray();
```

Alternatively, if the way you want to *use* the data is something that already accepts an `InputStream`, just use the stream returned by `getBinaryStream`. Make sure you know when it's okay to close the stream though - some usages may read lazily.

Comment: Upvoting  to add to your million(s)!. Thanks for the inspiration.

Answer (score 0):

Our code base is using Java NIO for writing blobs to files.  The api is quite simple to use and removes the read/write loop from your code and pushes that logic into Java core apis.

```
         while (resultSet.next()) {
            String da_document_id = resultSet.getString(1);
            String file_name = resultSet.getString(2);

            Path path = java.nio.file.FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("c:\\databaseDoc.doc");
            InputStream is = resultSet.getBinaryStream(3);
            java.nio.file.Files.copy(is, path);
            System.out.println("da_document_id= " + da_document_id);
            System.out.println("file_name= " + file_name);
        }
```